# Trouble with classes in Java

Tags: java, class, switch-statement

I am kind of confused because I cannot figure out what am i doing wrong here. I have done almost everything I could but it is still not working. I am now clueless how to go forward from here. Please help and i really really appreciate for your possible solution. Thanks

```
public class Example {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    String cafescan;

    Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);   

       System.out.print ("Please enter the name of the cafe :" );
       cafescan = scan.nextLine();

       Cafe naam = new Cafe();
       naam.name = (cafescan);//THIS WORKS FINE 
       Cafe thau = new Cafe();
      thau.location = (location1);//THIS IS WHERE ERROR IS
              System.out.println (naam.setName());
          System.out.print   (thau.setLocation());
```

On my Cafe.jave file i have this:

```
public class Cafe{
String name;
String location;



    public String setName(){

        name=name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase()+ " Cafe";
        return name;
    }   

    public String setLocation(){
        char location1 = name.charAt(0);
      //SWITCH IS SUPPOSED TO WORK ACCORDING TO FIRST ALPHABET OF cafescan

        switch (location1)
        {
        case 'E':
            System.out.println("Rosedale");
            break;
        case 'M':
            System.out.println ("Parkville");
            break;
        case 'T':
            System.out.println ("Towson");
            break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Baltimore");


        }
        return location;
    }
```

}

Help me out gurus:)

Comment: `location1` is of which data type?

Comment: What is not working? What error do you get?

Comment: Are you getting error `Cannot find symbol location1` ?

Comment: Where have you defined/declared `location1` ?

Comment: location1 cannot be resolved to a variable- Thats the error

Comment: i think i defined it as char and it is supposed to work according to first alphabet of "string name"

Comment: This error has come because you have not declared the variable location1.

Declare it to type whatever you want and then define it by some values(Populating it from user or anywhere)

Answer (score 1):

first you have to declare location1. and them read that from your scanner

```
String location1= scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: You have to make setter and getter methods for name and location  fields in your Cafe class. Also create one constructor with parameters cafescan in Cafe class

Answer (score 0):

In your main method make Cafe object as follows :

```
 Cafe naam = new Cafe(cafescan);
```

Modify your cafe class as follows :

```
public class Cafe{
   String name;
   String location;


public Cafe(String name){
    setName();
    setLocation();
}

public String setName(){

    name=name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase()+ " Cafe";
    return name;
}   

public String setLocation() {
    char location1 = name.charAt(0);
    // SWITCH IS SUPPOSED TO WORK ACCORDING TO FIRST ALPHABET OF cafescan

    switch (location1) {
        case 'E':
            System.out.println("Rosedale");
            location = "Rosedale";
            break;
        case 'M':
            System.out.println("Parkville");
            location = "Parkville";
            break;
        case 'T':
            System.out.println("Towson");
            location = "Towson";
            break;
        default: {
            System.out.println("Baltimore");
            location = "Baltimore";
        }

    }
    return location;
}
```

}

Comment: This one worked!! Thanks a lot sir. I couldnt voted you coz i need 15 reputations. Lots of appreciation